# Can't order in query

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a query that needs to be ordered and then i need to select specific rows of from it.

Error:

> Additional information: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

What I am trying to do is the following:

```
"SELECT * FROM (SELECT" +
                        " Websites.Id as websiteId, " +
                        " Websites.Title, " +
                        " Websites.Description, " +
                        " Websites.Url, " +
                        " Websites.BannerURL,  " +
                        " (Select Count(*) From Votes where WebsiteID = Websites.Id And [Unique] = 1 And Date = '" +
                        Date + "') as TotalVotes, " +
                        " ISNULL((Select AVG(rating) From WebsiteRating where WebsiteID = Websites.Id), 5) as Rating, " +
                        " Users.Username, " +
                        " (Select Count(*) From Redirects where WebsiteID = Websites.Id And [Unique] = 1 And Date = '" +
                        Date + "') as Redirects, " +
                        " RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Websites.ID) " +
                        " FROM Websites " +
                        " INNER JOIN Users ON Websites.UserID = Users.Id " +
                        " Where Websites.Enabled = 1" +
                        " GROUP BY Websites.Title, Websites.Description, Websites.Url, Websites.BannerURL , Users.Username, Websites.Id" +
                        // Error
                        " ORDER BY Websites.Id DESC" +
                        ") as Table1 " +
                        "WHERE RowNum > " + number + " And RowNum <= " + amount + "";
```

When I do the order by after the:

```
"WHERE RowNum > " + number + " And RowNum <= " + amount + "";
```

Then it first selects the rows from 0 to 25 and then order it. But I would like to order it first and then select the rows 0 from 25 from that list.

I'm still a beginner with sql, always worked with Linq. But this is a old project of mine which still works with plain sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
"SELECT * FROM (SELECT" +
    " Websites.Id as websiteId, " +
    " Websites.Title, " +
    " Websites.Description, " +
    " Websites.Url, " +
    " Websites.BannerURL,  " +
    " (Select Count(*) From Votes where WebsiteID = Websites.Id And [Unique] = 1 And Date = '" +
    Date + "') as TotalVotes, " +
    " ISNULL((Select AVG(rating) From WebsiteRating where WebsiteID = Websites.Id), 5) as Rating, " +
    " Users.Username, " +
    " (Select Count(*) From Redirects where WebsiteID = Websites.Id And [Unique] = 1 And Date = '" +
    Date + "') as Redirects, " +
    " RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Websites.ID) " +
    " FROM Websites " +
    " INNER JOIN Users ON Websites.UserID = Users.Id " +
    " Where Websites.Enabled = 1" +
    " GROUP BY Websites.Title, Websites.Description, Websites.Url, Websites.BannerURL , Users.Username, Websites.Id" +
    ") as Table1 " +
    " WHERE RowNum > " + number + " And RowNum <= " + amount + "" +
    " ORDER BY RowNum DESC"
    ;
```

You already have ordered data prepared through RowNum, so you do not need TOP or ORDER in the subquery, just apply an order to the rows that get selected which occurs after the final where clause.

Comment: Thanks and if i would like to order by the subquery: TotalVotes?

Comment: You can order by any of the columns after the subquery is complete using the where clause position I introduced. But, remember your row selection is based on a specific order, so if you change the presentation order you also need to change the way RowNum is calculated too.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out ORDER BY Websites.Id DESC. 
& use order by desc this in

```
 RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Websites.ID Desc)
```

OR 
use this inside the subquery.(no commenting above line for this)

```
SELECT top 100 percent
```